# why this powershell http server code doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I copied and pasted this code https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/creating-powershell-web-server in a powershell console directory which contains an index.html file

when browsing to http://localhost:8080/index.html I get an error Oops, the page is not available!
Is there something wrong with the code I can't see what ?

```
    # enter this URL to reach PowerShell’s web server
$url = 'http://localhost:8080/'

# HTML content for some URLs entered by the user
$htmlcontents = @{
  'GET /'  =  '<html><building>Here is PowerShell</building></html>'
  'GET /services'  =  Get-Service | ConvertTo-Html

}

# start web server
$listener = New-Object System.Net.HttpListener
$listener.Prefixes.Add($url)
$listener.Start()

try
{
  while ($listener.IsListening) {  
    # process received request
    $context = $listener.GetContext()
    $Request = $context.Request
    $Response = $context.Response

    $received = '{0} {1}' -f $Request.httpmethod, $Request.url.localpath
    
    # is there HTML content for this URL?
    $html = $htmlcontents[$received]
    if ($html -eq $null) {
      $Response.statuscode = 404
      $html = 'Oops, the page is not available!'
    } 
    
    # return the HTML to the caller
    $buffer = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($html)
    $Response.ContentLength64 = $buffer.length
    $Response.OutputStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
    
    $Response.Close()
  }
}
finally
{
  $listener.Stop()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work if you go to just `http://localhost:8080/`, you'd have to also have an index.html listing in order to browse to that too.

Just modify the `$htmlContents` section like so:

```
# HTML content for some URLs entered by the user
$htmlcontents = @{
  'GET /'  =  '<html><building>Here is PowerShell</building></html>'
  'GET /services'  =  Get-Service | ConvertTo-Html
  'GET /index.html'  =  '<html><building>this is my index page</building></html>'
}
```

You could also have a statement like this.

```
$htmlcontents = @{
  'GET /'  =  '<html><building>Here is PowerShell</building></html>'
  'GET /services'  =  Get-Service | ConvertTo-Html
  'GET /index.html'  =  '<html><building>this is my index page</building></html>'
  'GET /fromPage.html' = Get-content "C:\temp\fence.txt"
}
```

[image]